# Error, Unable to set the formulaArray property of the range class

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I've created the following formula:

```
=IFNA(LOOKUP(10^99,--MID(O2,MIN(IF((--ISNUMBER(--MID(O2,ROW($1:$25),1))=0)*ISNUMBER(--MID(O2,ROW($2:$26),1)),ROW($2:$26))),ROW($1:$25))),SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&RIGHT(N2,4),LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(RIGHT(N2,4),ROW($1:$25),1))* ROW($1:$25),0),ROW($1:$25))+1,1)*10^ROW($1:$25)/10))
```

It looks at column "N" and bring through just the number string. If there is an N/A it will then do the same on column "O" which is ran as an array and it works fine.

Yet when I converted it to VBA code, I get the error mentioned in the title .

```
Range("L2").Select
    Selection.FormulaArray = _
        "=IFNA(LOOKUP(10^99,--MID(RC[3],MIN(IF((--ISNUMBER(--MID(RC[3],ROW(R1:R25),1))=0)*ISNUMBER(--MID(RC[3],ROW(R2:R26),1)),ROW(R2:R26))),ROW(R1:R25))),SUMPRODUCT(MID(0&RIGHT(RC[2],4),LARGE(INDEX(ISNUMBER(--MID(RIGHT(RC[2],4),ROW(R1:R25),1))* ROW(R1:R25),0),ROW(R1:R25))+1,1)*10^ROW(R1:R25)/10))"
```

What it going wrong?

Comment: `.FormulaArray` will only accept a 255 character or fewer string. Yours is too long.

Comment: what can I use in stead?

Comment: Can you show some sample data? It may be possible to shorten the formula.

Comment: You can put place holders in your formula to get around the limitation. As described here http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2005/01/10/entering-long-array-formulas-in-vba/

Comment: give some screenshot of the data

Answer (score 5):

thank you Dick for pointing me in the right directions and Rory for correcting my error

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/853889-long-array-visual-basic-applications-issue.html

Comment: In my case I also needed to append the following to each .Replace line:
, LookAt:=xlPart