# VBA insert big array formula - problem with replaces

Tags: excel, vba, array-formulas

Recently I came across an `Excel` limitation and learned that we can't write an array formula with more than 255 characters long directly on a cell using `VBA`.
The solution for this problem as I found on the web (including on SO: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30105324/error-unable-to-set-the-formulaarray-property-of-the-range-class)), is replacing parts of the formula once it's inserted on the cell.

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
Sub WriteFormulaArray()
    '------
        Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    '------
        Dim StrF1 As String: StrF1 = "=IFERROR(""PART2""/""PART3"",""PART4"")"
        Dim StrF2 As String: StrF2 = "SUMPRODUCT(IF(('01 - Histórico'!R5C6:R101641C6>=RC1-1)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C6:R101641C6<RC1+1)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C8:R101641C8>=R4C-0.125)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C8:R101641C8<R4C+0.125),'01 - Histórico'!R5C5:R101641C5),'01 - Histórico'!R5C10:R101641C10)"
        Dim StrF3 As String: StrF3 = "SUM(IF(('01 - Histórico'!R5C6:R101641C6>=RC1-1)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C6:R101641C6<RC1+1)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C8:R101641C8>=R4C-0.125)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C8:R101641C8<R4C+0.125),'01 - Histórico'!R5C5:R101641C5))"
        Dim StrF4 As String: StrF4 = "MIN(IF(('01 - Histórico'!R5C6:R101641C6>=RC1-1)*('01 - Histórico'!R5C6:R101641C6<RC1+1),'01 - Histórico'!R5C10:R101641C10))"
    '------
        SH.Cells(5, 2).FormulaArray = StrF1
        SH.Cells(5, 2).Replace """PART2""", StrF2, LookAt:=xlPart
        SH.Cells(5, 2).Replace """PART3""", StrF3, LookAt:=xlPart
        SH.Cells(5, 2).Replace """PART4""", StrF4, LookAt:=xlPart
    '------
End Sub
```

Well, the previous code is very hard to analyse because of the length and complexity of the formulas, but the routine doesn't do any of the replacements and writes just

```
{=IFERROR("PART2"/"PART3","PART4")}
```

on cell `B5` (and returns correctly `"PART4"`).

Then I tried to simplify the code to find the problem:

```
Sub WriteFormulaArrayTest()
    '------
        Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    '------
        SH.Cells(6, 2).FormulaArray = "=""TEST1"""
        SH.Cells(6, 2).Replace """TEST1""", """TEST2""", LookAt:=xlPart
    '------
End Sub
```

And it works just fine.
But when I write:

```
Sub WriteFormulaArrayTest()
    '------
        Dim SH As Worksheet: Set SH = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    '------
        SH.Cells(6, 2).FormulaArray = "=""TEST1"""
        SH.Cells(6, 2).Replace """TEST1""", "SUM(R5C6:R5C7)", LookAt:=xlPart
    '------
End Sub
```

the replace doesn't work again and I have the feeling that's the same problem of the first code.

Please note that the routine doesn't give any errors. It just simply doesn't do the replacements.

What am I missing here?? Thanks.

Comment: Shouldn't you include `=` before Sum ?

Comment: The code executes, it does not arises any errors, but it does nothing, and formulas don't work. I had a similar issue in the past. Please, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51196290/error-1004-when-trying-to-use-formulaarray-replace-trick-does-not-work

Comment: @MohitBansal the `=` is already there...

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns that worked! Thank you a lot! If you post your solution as an answer I'll accept it!

Comment: I tried on my Sheet .... Using `"TEST1"` this worked instead of `"""TEST1"""`.

Comment: Glad it worked, but it's not my answer, this question is a duplicate. :)

Comment: Yep! I guess I didn't do my research properly. Thanks anyway!